# Why Controller Action trigger more than once in mvc4

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc-4, c#-4.0

I am working on MVC 4. In my application controller action is triggering three times when I call that action from anchor tag.

How can I handle this?

Here is my anchor tag

```
href="@Url.Action("../Post_Wiz_Jobs/Delete_Wiz_Job", new {jobid=@item.JOB_ID })"
```

This is action.

```
 public ActionResult Delete_Wiz_Job(long jobid)
        {
            bllObj.Delete_Post_Wiz_Jobs(jobid);
            return View("Manage_Wiz_Jobs");
        }
```

Comment: Show your code samples.

Comment: Please add this to question itself

Comment: Do you have any javascript code that calls this action? Maybe you have a click event on some other button with the same class name. I'm just guessing here so please share some code with us

Comment: Thanks It is working if i remove class from that . Here i am using anchor tag in foreach with same class that's the problem i think. But I didn't use that class in jquery i have used it for styles only